# socket.io-client-swift Package resolution Failed in Xcode13 Beta project

Tags: xcode, socket.io, xcode13

Hello to all i'm currently using the client of socket.io (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) with the new package manager of XCODE13 when i try to add the package using the package manager, i paste the URL of the repository(https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) into the search bar, the package appears, then i do click into 'Add Package' button, but i get this Error (see the image):

[image]

If i use the 'Add Anyway' option in order to add the package the line `import SocketIO` into my view file doesn't find the package gives me an error, and i have the same result importing the package via 'Add Local' option, i get the same error.

Thank you and sorry for the English

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I also have problems with socket.io using Carthage in Xcode 13 and Monterey

```
Building scheme "SocketIO" in Socket.IO-Client-Swift.xcodeproj

Build Failed: …
…
This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile.
```

**Edit:** I fixed my issue replacing the *1200* by *1300* in the carthage workaround [script](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Xcode12Workaround.md)